# how to give access to the user at the moment when the bootstrap modal window is open

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get user opportunity work with form on main page while modal window is opened. 
I've tried to google it, but modal windows aren't created for that, so google didnt let me answer.

Comment: Can you share your minimal code?

Comment: Can you please specify actual problem? Modal is opened and form is not working?

Comment: I can’t do this because I have an agreement with the non-disclosure authorities

Comment: You mean that when the modal is opened, you cannot ' touch '  the rest of the page ? well that's because that's the idea of the modal :) . Check the css styles applied to it. It has an overlay with some z-index that covers the rest of the page. I am sure you will figure it out

Comment: Now modal is opened, but user cant click on any thing under modal

Comment: @MihaiT yep u're right thank u)

Comment: Should i write it as an answer as well ? Did my comment solve your problem ?

Comment: Maybe something more like a [popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) would solve your use case. It can provide helpful information, but doesn't cover up much of the page.

Comment: @MihaiT it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You mean that when the modal is opened, you cannot ' touch ' the rest of the page ?

That's how modals work. The appear above the content and also have an overlay that with a z-index covers the rest of the page making it unreacheable, and that's why the user cannot touch the rest of the elements. So he cannot fill out the form ( in your case ).

In bootstrap modals this overlay  is called `modal-backdrop`

Remove the z-index from the `modal-backdrop`( overwrite it ) with maybe `.modal-backdrop { z-index: 0 }` and you will solve your problems.

But maybe you need to use something else instead of modal. Maybe some dialogs etc.